# php Пример с датами

Tags: php, mysql

Никак не могу выполнить вот этот пример. Никак не могу разобраться как отнимать от одной даты другую, все время выдает дату 1970 01 01.

24 часа - (текущая дата - дата из таблицы mysql)

Пример:
0000.00.00 24:00:00 - (2017.10.30 19:14:00 - 2017.10.30 14:14:00)
Ответ: 0000.00.00 19:00:00

дата в таблице в формате datetime;

результат нужно получить в формате datetime (h:i:s);
Все даты по умолчанию корректны, проверки выполнять не нужно

Comment: зависит от того, что вы хотите получить. например значение в днях можно получить с помощью datediff https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff

Comment: результат нужно получить в часах, минутах и секундах

Comment: в каком формате текущая дата, в каком - в бд ?

Comment: И да, дату 1970.01.01 очень даже может выдавать, видимо это не чистая дата а с временем, вот ее время и есть искомое. выделить только время в нужном формате time_format()

Comment: а если `(текущая дата - дата из таблицы mysql)` отрицательная?

Comment: она по умолчанию не может быть такой в проекте.

Comment: Только время получить в формате datetime невозможно, потому что тип данных datetime предполагает и наличие даты, а не только времени. из документации на datetime "_The supported range is '1000-01-01 00:00:00' to '9999-12-31 23:59:59'_". нулевой даты быть не может. если же получается значение типа timestamp то в нем базовая дата 01.01.1970. вот если бы вы использовали тип данных time, тогда уже был бы другой разговор

Comment: И кстати, что означает "_datetime (Y-m-d h:i:s)_" тип данных datetime хранит дату во внутреннем представлении, у него нет никакого формата. Формат может быть только в строковом представлении, а к нему в любом случае надо конвертировать соответствующими функциями (есть конечно формат отображения по умолчанию, но он зависит от используемого клиента и региональных настроек)

Comment: @Mike это все ерунда, как бы задачу понять, я вот даже вопрос не понимаю, как сформулироваь. Вот вычли мы из даты вторую, получили 10 лет, 5 месяцев, 3 дня... и что дальше? или надо взять только время в том и в том случае?

Comment: @splash58 Ну я бы лично понял что надо вывести что то вроде 91272:00:00 потому что просят  минимальной единицей выводить часы

Comment: *Никак не могу разобраться как отнимать от одной даты другую* вот так: `echo (new datetime())->diff(new datetime('2016-10-02 18:00'))->days;`

Comment: @Mike тогда получается (минус) 91272:00:00 - там же из 24 часов вычитается. Мне кажется, это "проблема xy"

Comment: @ВадимМороз объясните задачу или понятней, или, хотя бы, приведите пример данных и результата

Comment: может проще всё в число перегнать ? отнять два числа и обратно в дату ?

Comment: @ВадимМороз, а в чем вообще скрытый смысл такого выражения? из 24 часов вычесть разницу двух дата-времени? Логически попробуйте объяснить - что это?

Comment: что за год 0000?

Comment: @Jonny Manowar, да мне разницу между датами получить нужного, всего-то, для дальнейших вычислений

Comment: так ты от несуществующей даты отнимаешь

Comment: @ВадимМороз показжите как Вы это делаете - не строчку текста как пример, а именно Ваш запрос в бд или код php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конвертируйте в timestamp и вычесляйте.

```
mysql> SELECT unix_timestamp('2017-11-01 23:19:00')-unix_timestamp('2017-10-31 23:19:00');
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| unix_timestamp('2017-11-01 23:19:00')-unix_timestamp('2017-10-31 23:19:00') |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                                                                       86400 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select sec_to_time(86400);
+--------------------+
| sec_to_time(86400) |
+--------------------+
| 24:00:00           |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT sec_to_time(unix_timestamp('2017-11-01 23:19:00')-unix_timestamp('2017-10-31 23:19:00'));
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| sec_to_time(unix_timestamp('2017-11-01 23:19:00')-unix_timestamp('2017-10-31 23:19:00')) |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| 24:00:00                                                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```